# Own offsetof implementation produces warning

Tags: c, macros

I wrote a small piece of code to understand how the offsetof macro works in the background. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>  

int main(void)
{
    /* Getting the offset of a variable inside a struct */
    typedef struct {
        int a;
        char b[23];
        float c;
    } MyStructType;

    unsigned offset = (unsigned)(&((MyStructType * )NULL)->c);

    printf("offset = %u\n", offset);

    return 0;
}
```

However, if I run it I get a warning message:

WARNING: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]

However, if I look at the original offsetof macro in c, the code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stddef.h> 

int main(void)
{
    /* Getting the offset of a variable inside a struct */
    typedef struct {
        int a;
        char b[23];
        float c;
    } MyStructType;

    unsigned offset = offsetof(MyStructType, c);

    printf("offset = %u\n", offset);

    return 0;
}
```

So why do I get the warning as I cast to unsigned ? It appears to be the type for the offsetof macro. This is puzzling me.

Comment: `of different size` means that the value of a pointer might not fit into an `unsigned`. You should cast to `uintptr_t`.

Comment: My guess? You're on a 64-bit system where pointers are 64 bits wide, and `unsigned` (a.k.a. `unsigned int`) is 32 bits wide. Use `uintmax_t` or `uintptr_t` or `size_t` instead.

Comment: Note that `&((MyStructType * )NULL)->c` dereferences a `NULL` pointer and is undefined behavior.

Comment: You may need to cast to `uintptr_t` and then to `size_t` (since `offsetof` is supposed to produce a `size_t`).

Comment: It works fine without warnings if I write: size_t offset = (size_t)(&((MyStructType * )NULL)->c);

Comment: However, than why does the standard offsetof is allowed to use the unsigned type ?

Comment: @Meerkat The standard `offsetof` uses the `size_t` type. That might be the same as `unsigned int` or `unsigned long` or some other unsigned type. It might be narrower than `uintptr_t`, so you might need to cast the pointer to `uintptr_t` to suppress a "cast from pointer to integer of different size" warning before casting the `uintptr_t` value to `size_t` (which shouldn't produce any warning).

Comment: @Meerkat: It's not. Your code is just assigning the result into a variable of type `unsigned`.

Comment: @Ian Abbott: But if I understand correctly: with your approach you can get away with the warning, but if uintptr_t has a higher range than size_t, than the end result of casting from uintptr_t to size_t can still be erroneous ?

Comment: @Meerkat It is only erroneous if the `uintptr_t` value does not fit in a `size_t`. But since `size_t` can hold the size of any object, it can also hold the offset of any member of a struct object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mch commented, `unsigned` is not the right type; it's 32-bit on pretty much all real-world systems. The `offsetof` macro is supposed to produce a result of type `size_t`, which is what you "should" be casting to here. I think you're confused by the code you found storing the result into an object of type `unsigned`; that's okay as long as they're sure the value is small, but it doesn't mean the type of the expression `offsetof(MyStructType, c);` was `unsigned`. C allows you to silently assign a larger integer type into a smaller one.

However, no matter what you do, **this is not a valid implementation of `offsetof` and has undefined behavior** (via applying `->` to an invalid pointer). The way you get a working `offsetof` without UB is `#include <stddef.h>`.

Comment: So C does not produce a warning in case of silently assigning a larger integer type into a smaller one ?

Comment: note: your compiler probably implements offsetof this way anyway, but they're allowed to do that because they know how their own compiler works. You're not allowed to do it because someone might try to use a compiler where it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @user253751: No, it doesn't, because C requires the result of `offsetof` to be an integer constant expression and this is not one.

Comment: @ R.. GitHub STOP HELPING ICE : thanks for your answer, but I do not really understand your explanation :(

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE There is the get out clause "An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions." Some implementations actually do implement `offsetof` using the address operator, e.g. MSVC.